# How to use cat with socket?

Tags: sockets, unix, cat

While reading the source code of `cat` command, I found `cat` command supports for reading from socket. You can view the source at http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/bin/cat/cat.c.html. But I've never use this command with socket: just quickly viewing a file or concatenating multiple files. What can I do with `cat` + socket? Can you give an interesting example of using `cat` command reading from a socket? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not plug your cat in a socket: it may get electrocuted :)    (I'm sorry, I couldn't resist).

Comment: Do you have a programming context for this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using unix tools. It would be better suited for [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/gomlCAp.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

use "netcat" which on unix/linux is the command `nc`.  You most likely want to be the client socket, so something like `cat <filename> | nc <ip> <port>`

Comment: The role of that example of `cat` is just passing the contetns to `/dev/stdout` (as we always do). So, I want to know, can we use `cat` as a server side? Instead of `nc -l <ip> <port>`?

Answer (score 0):

The cat source code you found contains some magic to call socket() and connect() when you try to cat a socket. It doesn't contain any listen() or accept() so there's no way it can do the "server side" stuff. And it works with unix domain sockets, not inet sockets, so don't think it's for cat'ing stuff across an actual network. Unix domain sockets are just endpoints for local inter-process communication.

I can't imagine what use case they had in mind when they added this feature to cat.

Comment: Thanks. To be calm, what you are saying is perfectly right: I found no `listen` in the code. Thanks again.